# Simplest way to upload images

Tags: java, php, upload

what is the simplest way to upload multi images (like 30-50) at once using PHP to process them?

Do you know any js/ajax script? Or it possible to use java uploader like on facebook?

I don't need images to use them on WYSIWYG editor, but to upload images per album. so all at once

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+multiple+upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a progress bar while uploading you can try [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/), which is a Flash/Javascript uploader. It also opens a multi select file dialog, which is a big advantage of Flash. However, it can upload only one file per http request, and it is not so simple because you have to do some js coding if you want the progress bar(s).

If you'll use it, be careful with IE6 becuase it doesn't return what the script outputted.

Comment: this could work, what do you mean for progress bar? it seems it has it

Comment: Almost everything(except for the button) is controlled by Javascript. Swfupload calls your event handlers, with which you can control the DOM, making a progressbar. If it is enough, you can copy the code from examples. If you need something more, you have to write it.

Comment: got it, do you know any other option?